Can $\aleph_0 + $ a Dedekind-finite be a successor of $\aleph_0$
Is it consistent with ZF that there is a Dedekind-finite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\aleph_0 + \kappa > \aleph_0$ and there is no cardinal between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_0 + \kappa$? (Here cardinal means equivalence class of sets up to bijection).
Clearly any infinite Dedekind-finite $\kappa$ will satisfy $\aleph_0 + \kappa > \aleph_0$ but i have no idea about the second part.

It's not always true for every Dedekind finite set. Suppose that $A$ is amorphous, then $\mathcal P(A)$ is Dedekind finite.
However, $\aleph_0<\aleph_0+A<\aleph_0+\mathcal P(A)$.
On the other hand, it is certainly consistent, for example, if $A$ is amorphous, then any Dedekind infinite subset of $A+\omega$ injects into $\omega$ or has the same size as $A+\omega$.

Why does $A$ being amorphous imply any subset of $A+\omega$ injects into $\omega$, into $A$ or has same size as $A+\omega$?

@Carla_ I don't think that's quite right (e.g. $A + 2$ lacks this property) but the example still works. If $S\subseteq A \cup \mathbb N$ has $\aleph_0\le |S|$, then $S\cap \mathbb N$ must be infinite. If $S\cap A$ is finite then $|S| = \aleph_0.$ If $S\cap A$ is infinite, then $|S|= |A|+ \aleph_0.$

@spaceisdarkgreen: I should have really just gone to bed. Thanks for reading through the mistake and clarifying the argument.
